# Is it possible to render a "runtime:shiny" rmarkdown (.rmd) file, using an action button, in a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

Let's say we have this "runtime: shiny" RMD file I built on RStudio. It has 4 main parts:

````r
    ---
    title: "Theory"
    output: html_document
    runtime: shiny
    ---

    Part 1: html code
    <style type="text/css">

    h1.title {

    text-align: center;
    color: DarkBlue;
    font-size: 38px;

    }

    p{

    font-size: 18pt;
    font-family: times, serif;
    }
    </style>


    <br>
    </br>

    ---

    Part2: Inline equations

    <p>
    This is an inline equation: $y = \frac{a}{b}$
    </p>

    <br>
    </br>

    ---

    Part3: Standalone equations

    $$y = \frac{a}{b} $$

    <br>
    </br>

    ---

    Part4: Embedded shiny inputs and outputs

    ```{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}
    inputPanel(
      selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
                  choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20),

      sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
                  min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
    )

    renderPlot({
      hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
           xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser eruption duration")

      dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
      lines(dens, col = "blue")
    })
````

I can "Run Document" that in rStudio and it works perfectly.

Now I save that .rmd file and then reference it later while building my shiny app:

```
   library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    shinyWidgets::panel(
    fluidRow(
      column(12, align="center",
             actionButton("rmd", "Test")
      )
    ))
#    ,includeHTML(rmarkdown::render("test_rmd.Rmd"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
                  observeEvent(input$rmd, {
                    output$markdown <- renderUI({
                      includeHTML(rmarkdown::render("test_rmd.Rmd"))
                    })
                  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When I run the app, it fails to successfully display all 4 parts of the "runtime: shiny" rmd file other than the text itself.
The reason I am asking is because I eventually want to build an action button that, when clicked, will display the "runtime: shiny" rmd file.

**Is it not possible to render "runtime: shiny" rmd files because they they are incompatible with the shiny app format?**

P.S. I can mostly solve this problem by converting the rmd to an html **IF part 4 (the "Embedded shiny inputs and outputs") is removed** (otherwise I get an error). But I want to keep that if possible. Would make my life much easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code need some adjustments (if you don't mind).
Most importantly, you need to embed a [inline Shiny application](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/shiny-embedded.html#shiny-embed-inline) (inputs and outputs) within `.Rmd` by using `shinyApp()` function (Part 4):

````
---
title: "Theory"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---

Part 1: hidden css code

```{css part-1, echo = FALSE}
.h1.title {
  text-align: center;
  color: DarkBlue;
  font-size: 38px;
  }

.p{
  font-size: 18pt;
  font-family: times, serif;
  }
```

<br>
</br>

---

Part2: Inline equations

<p>
This is an inline equation: $y = \frac{a}{b}$
</p>

<br>
</br>

---

Part3: Standalone equations

$$y = \frac{a}{b} $$

<br>
</br>

---

Part4: Embedded shiny inputs and outputs

```{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    inputPanel(
      selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
                  choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20),

      sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
                  min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
    ),
    plotOutput("eruptionsPlot")),
    
    server = function(input, output) {
      output$eruptionsPlot = renderPlot({
      hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
           xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser eruption duration")

      dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
      lines(dens, col = "blue")
    })
    },
    options = list(height = "600px")
)
```
````

Now, to render `runtime: shiny` (or any other RMarkdown `output: html_document`) within shiny app, I would use `includeHTML` [function](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.11/include.html):

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    includeHTML(rmarkdown::render("ShinyRMarkdownFile.Rmd"))
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

With `includeMarkdown` function you can only render Markdown files `.md` and with `includeHTML` you can load HTML output of rendered RMarkdown file.
Also, there might be other solutions...

Comment: Huh, I tried your code and the page failed to render. I just tried running it in a normal rscript.

Comment: I'm using the latest versions of R (v. 3.6.2) and RStudio (v.1.3.776-2 [Preview](https://rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/)); also, rmarkdown, knitr and shiny packages. Does this help?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I figured it out, thanks to Radovan Miletic. This is the code I am using for the RMD ("test_rmd.Rmd") file:

````
---
title: "Theory"
output: html_document
runtime: shiny
---


Part 1: hidden css code

<style type="text/css">

h1.title {

text-align: center;
color: DarkBlue;
font-size: 38px;

}

p{

font-size: 18pt;
font-family: times, serif;
}

p1{

font-size: 14pt;
font-family: times, serif;
}

</style>


<br>
</br>

---

Part2: Inline equations

<p>
This is an inline equation: $y = \frac{a}{b}$
</p>

<br>
</br>

---

Part3: Standalone equations

$$y = \frac{a}{b} $$

<br>
</br>

---

Part4: Embedded shiny inputs and outputs

```{r eruptions, echo=FALSE}
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    inputPanel(
      selectInput("n_breaks", label = "Number of bins:",
                  choices = c(10, 20, 35, 50), selected = 20),

      sliderInput("bw_adjust", label = "Bandwidth adjustment:",
                  min = 0.2, max = 2, value = 1, step = 0.2)
    ),
    plotOutput("eruptionsPlot")),

    server = function(input, output) {
      output$eruptionsPlot = renderPlot({
      hist(faithful$eruptions, probability = TRUE, breaks = as.numeric(input$n_breaks),
           xlab = "Duration (minutes)", main = "Geyser eruption duration")

      dens <- density(faithful$eruptions, adjust = input$bw_adjust)
      lines(dens, col = "blue")
    })
    },
    options = list(height = "600px")
)
```
````

This is the code I am using for shiny app:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    shinyWidgets::panel(
    fluidRow(
      column(12, align="center",
             actionButton("rmd", "Test")
      )
    ))

,uiOutput("test")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
                  observeEvent(input$rmd, {
                    output$test <- renderUI({
                      withMathJax(includeHTML(rmarkdown::render("test_rmd.Rmd")))
                    })
                  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```